Error: subprocess-exited-with-error When Install RASA in PyCharm
When Installing RASA in PyCharm Display Error: subprocess-exited-with-error
 File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0g75ai8n\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 332, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0g75ai8n\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 302, in _get_build_requires      
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0g75ai8n\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 503, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0g75ai8n\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 318, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 34, in <module>
      RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

    

I tried to make RASA ChatBot

"RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required." Which version of Python are you running?
